# Suppress all warnings of a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

What is the easiest way to suppress all warnings from Visual Studio (and possibly Roslyn Analyzers)  for a certain method? Like I copy-paste code from a stackoverflow answer into a new method of my class and the code doesn't comply with my coding guidelines but also I don't want to change it and I don't want to insert lots of `pragma warning disable` directives or lots of `SuppressMessage` attributes.

Regarding ReSharper warnings I can simply add the following attribute to the method:

```
 [SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "All")]
```

but this works only for the ReSharper warnings, not for those from Visual Studio.

Comment: You can put `// <autogenerated />` at the very top of the file. But this works only for entire files.

Comment: @PMF That might be helpful if I put all copy-pasted code in a dedicated class, but I prefer organizing things by topic not by origin. Thanks Though!

Comment: What is so bad about `#pragma warning disable` above the method and `#pragma warning restore` below it?

Comment: I can understand that. Normally I just reformat such code to fit my needs, typically it isn't much more than a single function anyway.

Comment: @Petrusion Nice! I did some googling and didn't find a single sample that didn't include a rule in that directive like `CA2200` so I assumed a rule has to be provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable all warnings for a single method:

```
#pragma warning disable
void MethodWithWarnings()
{
   ...
}
#pragma warning restore
```